# Why previous state in SetSate hook is turning out to be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, use-effect, use-state

Code Snippet:

```
const [users,setUsers]=useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  for(let x in array){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref(`/users/${array[x]}`);
      ref.on('value', snapshot => {
        let data = snapshot.val();
         
         setUsers((prev)=>[...prev,data])
  }
},[])
```

`array` contains list of user ids.
Data contains the right value returned by snapshot.val().

If I do `console.log(users)` the 1st line inside useEffect, it is an empty array which is the expected value.

I don't understand why `prev` is  turning out to be undefined in `setUsers`

Comment: Are you sure its `undefined` or `[]`?

Comment: Can u post your code like how are you trying? For us it works correctly.

Comment: It has worked perfectly for me everytime. Just this one time, it is returning undefined. I want to know if there can be any possible way by which prev can turn out to be undefined instead of []